# How to count Virtual Cores on a VM in C or CPP

Tags: c, virtual-machine, processor, cpu-cores

I have a Windows Server 2012R2 VM running on VMWare Workstation 14 and Windows 10 Pro x64. Using C/CPP, I need to be able to count the number of Virtual Cores.  I used the example at the bottom of this  [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlogicalprocessorinformation).

I ran it on the 2012R2 VM. It prints the number of processors, physical core, logical processors,etc, but not the Virtual Cores. Is there any way to get/compute that count?

Comment: Is a virtual core different from a logical processor?

Comment: I don't this so. This [article](https://www.itprotoday.com/server-virtualization/understanding-virtual-and-logical-processors) was one of the ones I read. He talks about Virtual Processors per Logical Processor.

Comment: That relates the inside cores to the outside cores. When you're inside the VM, your  VM virtual cores "are" the logical cores, as far as any software is concerned.

Comment: Also, that article you linked to isn't clear on the distinction  between logical cores and physical cores. A single physical core of a processor can have multiple logical cores. Outside of the context of VMs, virtual cores are synonymous with logical cores. The article is relating the number of cores visible inside the VM to the number of logical (virtual) cores of the host.